# How do I delete nan-valued keys from one dictionary into another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**I have this dictionary :**

```
d = {4: {0: [12], 1: [194]}, 8: {0: [222], 1: nan}, 18: {0: [60], 1: nan},
      19: {0: [128], 1: nan}, 21: {0: [54], 1: nan}}
```

**the output should look like this:**

```
  d = {4: {0: [12], 1: [194]}, 8: {0: [222] }, 
       18: {0: [60] }, 19: {0: [128]}, 21: {0: [54]}}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `into another dictionary`. It would help if you added your desired result.

Comment: @Mark ok, I write the desired output.

Comment: thank you very much was this what I needed! @Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively pass the dictionaries to a function that filters out key with `nan` values. For example:

```
from math import nan

d = {4: {0: [12], 1: [194]}, 8: {0: [222], 1: nan}, 18: {0: [60], 1: nan},
     19: {0: [128], 1: nan}, 21: {0: [54], 1: nan}}

def clean_nan(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return {k: clean_nan(v) for k, v in d.items() if v == v}
    return d

clean_nan(d)
```

Gives the result:

```
{4: {0: [12], 1: [194]},
 8: {0: [222]},
 18: {0: [60]},
 19: {0: [128]},
 21: {0: [54]}}
```

This assumes the lists don't contain `nan`, but if they did it would be easy to add another clause to filter those.